# lapply & sapply on data.frame to test all elements in each column to get a single logical

Tags: r, lapply, tidyverse, sapply

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(dates1 = c(20120631,NA,20130504,20161211),
                dates2 = c(201604,201503,NA,201201))
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar==8 %>% all)
lapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar==8 %>% all)
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar==8 %>% any)
lapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar==8 %>% any)
```

If I have any clue about the way `sapply` & `lapply` work (and I'm pretty sure this worked yesterday), this should give me back a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It's not. I'm getting back a matrix of true and false. That's not what `any()` or `all()` is supposed to do.

sapply results:

```
     dates1 dates2
[1,]  FALSE  FALSE
[2,]  FALSE  FALSE
[3,]  FALSE  FALSE
```

lapply results:

```
$dates1
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

$dates2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

WTH is going on??

Comment: The `nchar == 8` bit breaks the pipe chain sequence. I've never seen a pipe sequence constructed quite like that before.

Comment: You may want to do, for example, `'acvbdftr' %>% (function(x) nchar(x) == 8)`

Comment: Remove the any/all and try it on your own session. It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the problem with the code is order of operations.  `%>%` is performed before `==` but we want `==` performed before the last `%>%` so use parentheses to force this.  The innermost parentheses shown here are actually not needed since the default order of operations already works for those; however, we added them in addition to the ones needed for clarity.  See `?Syntax` for the complete table giving the order of operations.

```
sapply(df,function(x) ((x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar) == 8) %>% all)
## dates1 dates2 
##   TRUE  FALSE
```

however, this might be better written as the following using the facts that:

- `nchar` already coerces its argument to character so we can eliminate `as.character`
- `. %>% whatever` can be used to define a function wjere `whatever` is replaced with the function body assuming the single argument is dot (.)
- `{...}` can be used to prevent automatic . insertion:

giving:

```
df %>% sapply(. %>% na.omit %>% { nchar(.) == 8 } %>% all)
## dates1 dates2 
##   TRUE  FALSE
```

or if what is desired is a single logical over all columns then:

```
p <- df %>% sapply(na.omit) %>% { nchar(.) == 8 } 

p %>% all
## [1] FALSE

p %>% any
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Since OP needs a single logical for each column, then you need to pipe `all` inside the sapply function...

Comment: Thought it said you test all elements in each column.. not in all columns. Also you can get a clue from what he is trying to do. But also reading the question, one get confused since he is expecting only a single result

Comment: I have modified the solution to show both interpretations.

Comment: This is a great answer. Yes, I wanted a single logical for each column (multiple logicals, one for each column... rather than several arrays of logicals).

Answer (score 1):

Writing `x %>% nchar == 8 %>% any` is equivalent to `nchar(x) == any(8)`, and so will not be the same as `any(nchar(x) == 8)`

I think this is what you're after

```
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% (function(x) nchar(x) == 8) %>% all)
# dates1 dates2 
#   TRUE  FALSE 
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% (function(x) nchar(x) == 8) %>% any)
# dates1 dates2 
#   TRUE  FALSE
```

Equivalently:

```
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar %>% `==`(8) %>% all)
# dates1 dates2 
#   TRUE  FALSE 
sapply(df,function(x) x %>% na.omit %>% as.character %>% nchar %>% `==`(8) %>% any)
# dates1 dates2 
#   TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get rid of the loops is to use the vectorized nature of `nchar`

```
 p <- colMeans(nchar(as.matrix(df)),na.rm = T)==8
 any(p)
[1] TRUE
 all(p)
[1] FALSE
```

or using piping:

```
p<- df %>% as.matrix %>% nchar %>% colMeans(na.rm = T) %>% {. == 8}

p %>% any
[1] TRUE

 p %>% all
[1] FALSE
```